# c# LINQ joining to comma separated string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string of comma separated values called driverids.

1. Should I use the comma separated list or the array that this comma separated list comes from to use this in a join.
2. How would I use a join in linq to these driverids?

```
_currentDriverData.AddRange(elementsCurrent.Join(driverids)

// gets distinct driver ids from the driver duty status change logs;
string driverids = string.Join(",", _logsDutyStatusChange
                         .Select(item => item.did)
                         .Distinct()
                         .ToArray());

//gets all current driver information
//_currentDriverData.AddRange(elementsCurrent.Where(drivers)

_currentDriverData.AddRange(elementsCurrent.Join(driverids).Select.........
```

Comment: What are you trying to join them to?

Comment: I am trying to get only those driver id's in my select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do something like this (assuming `_currentDriverData` us a list of ids):

```
_currentDriverData.AddRange(commaSeparatedString.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyElements).ToList());
```